# Expanded variable as argument of another command via concatenation in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Imagine I want to call some command `some-command` via `$()` with an argument stored in another variable `argument`, the latter containing space.

1. With my current understanding, the fact that `result="$(some-command $argument)"` (e.g. expansion) leads to passing two arguments is as expected.
2. **Question part:** why does the `result="$(some-command "$argument")"` (e.g. concatenation) lead to the desired result of passing *one* single argument?

More details:

`./some-command`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Arg 1: $1"
echo "Arg 2: $2"
```

`./test-script`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export PATH="`pwd -P`:$PATH"

argument="one two"

echo "Calling with expansion"
res="$(some-command $argument)"
echo $res

echo "Calling with concatenation"
res="$(some-command "$argument")"
echo $res
```

Calling `test-script` leads to the following output:

```
Calling with expansion
Arg 1: one Arg 2: two
Calling with concatenation
Arg 1: one two Arg 2:
```

I seem to not grasp when smth is expanded / evaluated and how the expanded variables are grouped into arguments passed to scripts.

Thank you!

P.S. Bonus curiosity is why `result="$(some-command \"$argument\")"` does not work at all.

Comment: Do you have a space after `some-command` or not?

Comment: Good catch, inactual scripts space is there, corrected!

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is your friend -- it explains why argument lists should __never__ be stored as strings, and what to use instead (short form: either arrays or functions, depending on the context).

Comment: ...as for `result="$(some-command \"$argument\")"`, if `argument="one two"`, it's running `some-command '"one' 'two"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how quoting and expansions work in bash. In fact, double quotes after `=` are not needed, as word-splitting is not performed, so

```
result=$(some-command "$argument")
```

should work the same way.

There's no "concatenation" going on. Bash treats the string inside `$()` as a command and runs all the expansions on it before running it.

So, what happens with `some-command "$argument"`? First, the parameter expansion expands $argument into a string containing spaces. When word-splitting happens, it notes the string was enclosed in double quotes, so it keeps it as a single string.

Comment: I see, thanks! So in this case the relation between the outer pair of quotes and the inner one is not the same as in say `res="literal1"$stringvar2"literal3"`? I.e. the quoted part is not “switched off/on” but bash rather recognizes those as quotes inside quotes?

Comment: @agronskiy: Exactly.

Comment: Thank you! Should have had closer look to the dup question...